# ttf fonts added in class library project cannot be found in iOS 15.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have ttf fonts added in the "Resources" folder of the iOS project of a Xamarin.Forms class library project. I am using the ttf fonts to render toolbar icons in my library. I have added this class library as a reference to an application project.

But when the application is run, the fonts are not available. The below code returns null.

```
string resourcePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("FontName", "ttf");
```

The build action of the ttf files are `BundleResource`. The fonts are available only if I copy the ttf files to the "Resources" folder of the iOS project of the application.

This problem occurs only in iOS versions > 15.0. Below 15.0, the fonts from the class library are loaded without any problem. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your issue but it works well , I followed all the steps you provided please check it if it differs from yours .

1. Create a `iOS class library`.

   [image]
2. Add the file into `Resources` folder .
3. Set build action as `BundleResource`.
4. Run on iOS 15.2 .

The code works perfectly , `resourcePath` has value.