# NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource returns null for png image included in the Resources folder

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin.Forms class library project that I refer to in a Xamarin.Forms application project. In the iOS project of the class library, I have included a png image in the `Resources` folder and set its "Build Action" to `BundleResource`.

When I try to load this image file in the library project using the below code, I get null value.

```
string imagePath = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource("ImageFileName", "png");
```

I had also tried setting the "Copy To Output" property of the image file to all available values (`Do not copy`, `Copy always`, `Copy if newer`). No matter which value is set, the path is returned as null.

I am using the iOS 15.0 simulator. I navigated to the bundle location of the application in the simulator's location in the Mac. I could not see the image file in the application bundle.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you testing with `Xamarin.Forms class library` or `iOS class library` ? Based on the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693975/8187800) it works fine .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, I am testing with Xamarin.Forms class library. This problem occurs only in my Xamarin.Forms.iOS library. If I create a simple Xamarin.Forms class library from the VS project templates and include a bundle resource, I am able to get its resource path. I could not figure out what can be the possible reason that this issue occurs only in that particular class library.

Comment: In this scenario you can remove the old one and add the new one .